# Python selenium web driver example from django docs error: 'f.QueryInterface is not a function'

Tags: python, django, testing, selenium, circleci

I want to write some Selenium unittests for Django app. We already have lots of regular python unittests. I've copied the [example selenium test from the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) (which is little more than a 'hello world' for selenium'):

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase


class MySeleniumTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        super(MySeleniumTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(MySeleniumTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_simple(self):
        self.selenium.get("/")
```

However, when I run this locally, or using [CircleCI](http://circleci.com/) (tests-in-the-cloud-as-a-service), I get this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_simple (proj.lib.tests.MySeleniumTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu//proj/proj/lib/tests.py", line 1347, in test_simple
    self.selenium.get("/")
  File "/home/ubuntu/proj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 185, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/ubuntu/proj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/proj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: u'f.QueryInterface is not a function' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.get (file:///tmp/tmpXXrLF6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9333)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpXXrLF6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11455)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpXXrLF6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11460)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpXXrLF6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11402)
```

This is Django 1.5.5, python 2.7, selenium python package 2.42.1

What's the problem? How do I get selenium working?

Comment: what version of firefox are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get` method requires a full URL. That is, the URI including the protocol and hostname/ip.

```
self.selenium.get("/")
# becomes
self.selenium.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011019/")
```